# how to convert a column of string to a list

Tags: python

I have select a string column from a table. Now I want to take all the values and convert to a list of string. I used the following code but it does not work.

```
top_feature = rf_varimp[['variable']].values.tolist()
top_feature
```

the output is:

```
[['mrkd100006'], ['mrkd100005'], ['ccs2376'], ['ccs644'], ['ccs3262']]
```

what I expect for the output is something like:

```
['mrkd100006', 'mrkd100005', 'ccs2376', 'ccs644', 'ccs3262']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a multi dimensional array by using

```
rf_varimp[['variable']].values.tolist()
```

Use the following instead

```
rf_varimp['variable'].values.tolist()
```

There is a subtle difference between `rf_varimp[['variable']]` and `rf_varimp['variable']` in that one is a `pandas.DataFrame` and the latter is a `pandas.Series`. Knowing the difference will save you a lot of hassle in the future with other `pandas` operations.

Comment: so rf_varimp[['variable']] is a data frame and rf_varimp['variable'] is a series?

Comment: yes exactly the case

Answer (score 1):

Pandas series can be cast to lists directly

```
list(rf_varimp['variable'])

Out:
['mrkd100006', 'mrkd100005', 'ccs2376', 'ccs644', 'ccs3262']
```